# How to make a list from sql with php while loops

Tags: php, sql, while-loop

So I have a database table, named `todolist`, and I want to display the whole to do list in a box. What I have right now is this:

```
$db = (INFO HERE :));    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM todolist";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
  echo "There is nothing else to do! :)";
} else {
}
```

What do I put in the else, for it to display everything on a list? Thanks

Comment: what list? what you want as expected outcome? Please show. A sample:-`else {
while($row = mysqli_ftech_assoc($result)){echo "<pre/>";print_r($row);}
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like below:

```
 <?php
    $db = (INFO HERE :));    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM todolist";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo "There is nothing else to do! :)";
    } 
    else{
        ?>
        <ul>
            <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                ?>
                  <li><?php echo $row["yourColumnName"] ?></li><?php                
            }?>
            </ul><?php
        }
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM todolist";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   echo "There is nothing else to do! :)";
   exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  // To see all data
       // print_r($row);
  //  to print single column value 
      //echo $row['id];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    //Do something here  with $row array , for example print_r
print_r($row);
}
```